A family of polynomials related to integer partitions
For a positive integer $n$, let $p(n)$ be the number of partitions of $n$.
For $1\le k\le n$, let $p(n,k)$ denote the number of partitions of $n$ having exactly $k$ terms; in other words, $p(n,k)$ is the number of ways to write $n$ as a sum of $k$ positive integers.
Let us introduce the polynomials
$$p_n(x)=\sum_{k=1}^np(n,k)x^{k-1}\ \ (n=1,2,3,\ldots).$$
For example,
$$p_5(x)=p(5,1)+p(5,2)x+p(5,3)x^2+p(5,4)x^3+p(5,5)x^4=1+2x+2x^2+x^3+x^4.$$
Note that $p_n(1)=p(n)$.  S. DeSalvo and I. Pak [Ramanujan J. 38 (2015), 61-73] used the Hardy-Ramanujan-Rademacher series for $p(n)$ to prove that the sequence $(p(n))_{n\ge 25}$ is log-concave, i.e., $p(n)^2\ge p(n-1)p(n+1)$ for any integer $n\ge 26$.
Now I state my following related conjecture.
Conjecture. For any positive integer $n$, all the coefficients of the polynomial $$p_{2n}(x)^2-p_{2n-1}(x)p_{2n+1}(x)$$ are nonnegative.
I have verified this for $n=1,2,\ldots,50$ via Mathematica. It seems that DeSalvo and Park's method does not work for the above new conjecture.
QUESTION。 Is the conjecture true? Any ideas to solve it?
Your comments are welcome!

What about $p_n^2-p_{n-1}p_{n+1}$ for odd $n$?

The second author of the cited paper is Igor Pak, not Park. And it is noticed in the paper that the log-concavity fails for all odd $n<25$.

@FedorPetrov, the $x^1$ coefficient of $p_n^2 - p_{n-1} p_{n+1}$ is $(-1)^n$.
